# CSS Grid, 4 large columns, 3 medium

Tags: php, css, zurb-foundation

I have a responsive grid using Foundation. I use PHP to generate each `row` of HTML, creating a new row every 3 columns.

```
<?php for($i=0 ; $i<12 ; $i++) {
if($i%4==0) { ?>
    <div class='row'>
<?php } else { ?>
   <div class='3-large 12-small columns'>
      <img src='xxx'>
   </div>
<?php }
if(($i+1)%4==0) { ?>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

I am attempting to display 4 columns for large screens (as above), and 3 columns for medium screens. Is this possible without using some server-side code to detect the device size?

Comment: It is not possible to detect the screen size server-side (PHP), however you can do so client-side (JavaScript). You can also create the rows using JavaScript

Comment: yes it's automatic work,but as a responsive

Comment: You can detect the client's screen size by sending it to the server using javascript. Such thing can be performed using an AJAX request which, on the page load, calls a PHP script telling it what's the client's resolution and waits for the server to answer with the content he needs. However, such kind of thing is not really responsive: it is usually enough to use **media queries** and create different layouts for different device sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way is to use  [visibility](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/visibility.html) classes in foundation -

```
<?php for($i=0 ; $i<12 ; $i++) {
if($i%4==0) { ?>
    <div class='row'>
<?php } else { ?>
   <div class='large-3 show-for-large-only  columns'>
      <img src='xxx'>
   </div>
<?php }
if(($i+1)%4==0) { ?>
    </div>
<?php } ?>

<?php for($i=0 ; $i<12 ; $i++) {
if($i%4==0) { ?>
    <div class='row'>
<?php } else { ?>
   <div class='small-4 show-for-small-only columns'>
      <img src='xxx'>
   </div>
<?php }
if(($i+1)%4==0) { ?>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

But this will result in repeating content in your html doc.

i suggest using [block grid](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/block_grid.html) of foundation

```
<div class='small-block-grid-3 large-block-grid-4'>
    <img src='xxx'>
    <img src='xxx'>
    <img src='xxx'>
    <img src='xxx'>
</div>
```

Comment: Block grid is perfect for this

Answer (score -1):

If you are using jQuery you can simply get by client-side size of window:

```js
$(window).height();   // returns height of browser viewport
$(document).height(); // returns height of HTML document
$(window).width();   // returns width of browser viewport
$(document).width(); // returns width of HTML document
```